# k-fold cross validation using DataLoaders in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I have splitted my training dataset into 80% train and 20% validation data and created DataLoaders as shown below. However I do not want to limit my model's training. So I thought of splitting my data into K(maybe 5) folds and performing cross-validation. However I do not know how to combine the datasets to my dataloader after splitting them.

```py
train_size = int(0.8 * len(full_dataset))
validation_size = len(full_dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, validation_dataset = random_split(full_dataset, [train_size, validation_size])

full_loader = DataLoader(full_dataset, batch_size=4,sampler = sampler_(full_dataset), pin_memory=True) 
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4, sampler = sampler_(train_dataset))
val_loader = DataLoader(validation_dataset, batch_size=1, sampler = sampler_(validation_dataset))
```

Comment: Take a look at [`torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset)

Answer (score 18):

I just wrote a cross validation function work with dataloader and dataset.
Here is my code, hope this is helpful.

```py
# define a cross validation function
def crossvalid(model=None,criterion=None,optimizer=None,dataset=None,k_fold=5):
    
    train_score = pd.Series()
    val_score = pd.Series()
    
    total_size = len(dataset)
    fraction = 1/k_fold
    seg = int(total_size * fraction)
    # tr:train,val:valid; r:right,l:left;  eg: trrr: right index of right side train subset 
    # index: [trll,trlr],[vall,valr],[trrl,trrr]
    for i in range(k_fold):
        trll = 0
        trlr = i * seg
        vall = trlr
        valr = i * seg + seg
        trrl = valr
        trrr = total_size
        # msg
#         print("train indices: [%d,%d),[%d,%d), test indices: [%d,%d)" 
#               % (trll,trlr,trrl,trrr,vall,valr))
        
        train_left_indices = list(range(trll,trlr))
        train_right_indices = list(range(trrl,trrr))
        
        train_indices = train_left_indices + train_right_indices
        val_indices = list(range(vall,valr))
        
        train_set = torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset(dataset,train_indices)
        val_set = torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset(dataset,val_indices)
        
#         print(len(train_set),len(val_set))
#         print()
        
        train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=50,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
        val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_set, batch_size=50,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
        train_acc = train(res_model,criterion,optimizer,train_loader,epoch=1)
        train_score.at[i] = train_acc
        val_acc = valid(res_model,criterion,optimizer,val_loader)
        val_score.at[i] = val_acc
    
    return train_score,val_score
        

train_score,val_score = crossvalid(res_model,criterion,optimizer,dataset=tiny_dataset)
```

---

In order to give an intuition of correctness for what we are doing, see the output below:

```
train indices: [0,0),[3600,18000), test indices: [0,3600)
14400 3600

train indices: [0,3600),[7200,18000), test indices: [3600,7200)
14400 3600

train indices: [0,7200),[10800,18000), test indices: [7200,10800)
14400 3600

train indices: [0,10800),[14400,18000), test indices: [10800,14400)
14400 3600

train indices: [0,14400),[18000,18000), test indices: [14400,18000)
14400 3600
```

Comment: Very good example, thank you for this. 
I think it would be great to separate dataset splitting and training. For example:
`metrics = k_fold(full_dataset, train_fn, **other_options)`, where `k_fold` function will be responsible for dataset splitting and passing `train_loader` and `val_loader` to `train_fn` and collecting its output into metrics. `train_fn` will be responsible for actual training and returning metrics for each K.

Comment: What are criterion and optimizer? Is optimizer something like AdamW?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [Cross validation for MNIST dataset with pytorch and sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996242/cross-validation-for-mnist-dataset-with-pytorch-and-sklearn) . The question asker implemented kFold Crossvalidation. Take especially a look a his own answer ( answered Nov 23 '19 at 10:34 ). He doesn't rely on random_split() but on sklearn.model_selection.KFold and from there constructs a DataSet and from there a Dataloader.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using KFOLD from sklearn and dataloader.

```
import torch
from torch._six import int_classes as _int_classes
from torch import Tensor

from typing import Iterator, Optional, Sequence, List, TypeVar, Generic, Sized

T_co = TypeVar('T_co', covariant=True)

class Sampler(Generic[T_co]):
    r"""Base class for all Samplers.

    Every Sampler subclass has to provide an :meth:`__iter__` method, providing a
    way to iterate over indices of dataset elements, and a :meth:`__len__` method
    that returns the length of the returned iterators.

    .. note:: The :meth:`__len__` method isn't strictly required by
              :class:`~torch.utils.data.DataLoader`, but is expected in any
              calculation involving the length of a :class:`~torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.
    """

    def __init__(self, data_source: Optional[Sized]) -> None:
        pass

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T_co]:
        raise NotImplementedError
        
class SubsetRandomSampler(Sampler[int]):
    r"""Samples elements randomly from a given list of indices, without replacement.

    Args:
        indices (sequence): a sequence of indices
        generator (Generator): Generator used in sampling.
    """
    indices: Sequence[int]

    def __init__(self, indices: Sequence[int], generator=None) -> None:
        self.indices = indices
        self.generator = generator

    def __iter__(self):
        return (self.indices[i] for i in torch.randperm(len(self.indices), generator=self.generator))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.indices) 


train_dataset = CustomDataset(data_dir=train_path, mode='train') )
val_dataset = CustomDataset(data_dir=train_path, mode='val') )

    fold = KFold(5, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed)
    for fold,(tr_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(fold.split(dataset)):
        # initialize the model
        model = smp.FPN(encoder_name='efficientnet-b4', classes=12 , encoder_weights=None, activation='softmax2d')
    
 
     
        loss = BCEDiceLoss()
        optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW([
            {'params': model.decoder.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-07/2}, 
            {'params': model.encoder.parameters(), 'lr': 5e-07},  
        ])
        scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, factor=0.15, patience=2)
    
  
    
        print('#'*35); print('############ FOLD ',fold+1,' #############'); print('#'*35);
        train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, 
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               num_workers=1,
                                               sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(tr_idx)
                                            )
        val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=val_dataset, 
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               num_workers=1,
                                               sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_idx)
                                            )
```

so when you write the DataLoader part, use the subsetRandomSampler, in this way, the sampler in the dataloader will always sample the train/valid indices generated by the kfold function randomly.