# Reproducibility in PyTorch with K-Fold Cross Validation

Tags: python, random, pytorch, cross-validation

I have recently started a new project using PyTorch and I am still new in AI. In order to perform  better on my dataset during training process I used cross-validation technique. Everyone seems to work fine but I am struggling with reproducibility. I even tried to set SEED number for each k-fold iteration but it does not seem to work at all. Changes in loss and accuracy are insignificant but they are. Before using cross-validation everything worked perfect. Thank you in advance.

Here is a for loop for my k-fold. I used a solution from:
[k-fold cross validation using DataLoaders in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883696/k-fold-cross-validation-using-dataloaders-in-pytorch)

```
K_FOLD = 5
fraction = 1 / K_FOLD
unit = int(dataset_length * fraction)

for i in range(K_FOLD):


    torch.manual_seed(SEED)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(SEED)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(SEED)            # if you are using multi-GPU.
    np.random.seed(SEED)                        # Numpy module.
    random.seed(SEED)                           # Python random module.
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True


    print("-----------K-FOLD {}------------".format(i+1))
    tr_ll = 0
    print("Train left begin:", tr_ll)
    tr_lr = i * unit
    print("Train left end:", tr_lr)
    val_l = tr_lr
    print("Validation begin:", val_l)
    val_r = i * unit + unit
    print("Validation end:", val_r)
    tr_rl = val_r
    print("Train right begin:", tr_rl)
    tr_rr = dataset_length
    print("Train right end:", tr_rr)
    # msg
    #         print("train indices: [%d,%d),[%d,%d), test indices: [%d,%d)"
    #               % (tr_ll,tr_lr,tr_rl,tr_rr,val_l,val_r))

    train_left_indices = list(range(tr_ll, tr_lr))
    train_right_indices = list(range(tr_rl, tr_rr))

    train_indices = train_left_indices + train_right_indices
    val_indices = list(range(val_l, val_r))
    # print("TRAIN Indices:", train_indices, "VAL Indices:", val_indices)

    train_set = torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset(DATASET, train_indices)
    val_set = torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset(DATASET, val_indices)
    # print("Length of train set:", len(train_set), "Length of val set:", len(val_set))
    
    image_datasets = {"train": train_set, "val": val_set}
    loader = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
                     for x in sets}
    dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}


    # training
    trained_model = train_model(AlexNet, CRITERION, OPTIMIZER,
                            dataloader=loader, dataset_sizes=dataset_sizes, num_epochs=EPOCHS, k_fold=i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the latest [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html), looks like you'll also need:

```py
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use it since I have and AdaptiveAveragePooling layer in my default AlexNet model from PyTorch Resources - what throws out the error
_adaptive_avg_pool2d_backward_cuda does not have a deterministic implementation, but you set 'torch.set_deterministic(True)'_

Comment: Well that answers the question then! It will never be reproducible exactly because some of the layers aren't deterministic. So you’re doing nothing wrong it’s just not possible to accomplish perfect reproducibility with that network

Comment: Understand, thank you so much. Can I somehow pass the output from last ConvLayer to FCC layer in Sequential without modyfing it. Because there is a middle AdaptiveAveragePool2d layer and I maybe could get rid of it

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped, feel free to accept it and/or upvote! And yes, passing the output from the last layer to the FCC layer should be possible. Feel free to submit a new question on that specifically if needed.