# Is k-folds cross validation a smarter idea than using a validation set instead?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, cross-validation, medical-imaging

I have a somewhat large (~2000) set of medical images I plan to use to train a CV model (using efficentnet architecture) in my workplace. In preparation for this, I was reading up on some good practices for training medical images. I have split the dataset by patients to prevent leakages and split my data in train:test:val in the order of 60:20:20. However, I read that k-folds cross validation was a newer practice then using a validation set, but I was recommended away from doing so as k-folds is supposed to be far more complicated. What would you recommend in this instance, and are there any other good practices to adopt?

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, design questions should be asked on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. In short, first it depends if you're going to do hyper-parameter tuning or train several models and select the best. If yes, you will need a  fresh test set. If not, you can either have evaluate with a single train/test split or with CV, knowing that CV gives a more reliable estimate of performance but requires more computation. See also [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/108792/why-is-the-k-fold-cross-validation-needed/108795#108795).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Common Practice

A train:test split with cross-validation on the training set is part of the standard workflow in many machine learning modules. For an example and further details, I recommend the excellent [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) article on it.

### Implementation

The implementation may be a little trickier but should not be prohibitive given the many code examples assuming you are using TF or Pytorch (see e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883696/k-fold-cross-validation-using-dataloaders-in-pytorch)).

### Should you be using k-fold cross validation?

Compared to a single validation set, k-fold cross-validation avoids over-fitting hyperparameters to a fixed validation set and makes better use of the available data by utilizing the entire training set across the folds, albeit at greater computational cost. Whether or not this makes a big difference depends on your task. 2000 images does not sound like a lot in computer vision terms, so making good use of the data may be relevant to you, especially if you plan on tuning hyperparameters.